# Django UserCreationForm extension

Tags: django, view

can i add fields like address,city,state,country,pincode and security question and answer to the extension of UserCreationForm that currently contains username,email,password1 and password2. if yes then please illustrate how?

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = EmailField(label=_("Email address"), required=True,
        help_text=_("Required."))
    city= forms.CharField(label= _("City"),max_length=20, required=True)
    state= forms.CharField(label= _("State"),max_length=20, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2","city","state")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.city = self.cleaned_data["city"]
        user.state = self.cleaned_data["state"]

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently you are extending UserCreationForm class if you have other fields in user model then you can use forms.ModelForm and just mention other fields.

for example

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','name', 'email', 'phone', 
              'address','city','state', 'first_time']
```

if you want to use custom form then.

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
      name = forms.CharField(label= _("Name"))
      address = forms.CharField(label=_("Address"))
      etc.
```

Comment: well that's doing a lot of things that are already done. That's the purpose of a framework, not creating the wheel again and again. I don't think that should be the accepted one but whatever

Comment: And that doesn't answer the 'extends UserCreationForm'. Here you're just passing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes just do like you did with email:

```
class UserCreationForm:
    a_field = WhateverField(whatever='whatever'...)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
```

The field is now added in your form.

Comment: how do i use a dropdown for country from a particular no of choices?

Comment: you can change your fields in the ```__init__()``` method. 
```self.fields['a_field']['property'] = ....``` and then just call the super ```super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(args, kwargs)```. But again that's another question, you should ask it.

Comment: There is a problem here. the fields that i added like address,country,state,etc are showing on the form but when i query like User.country or anything except the inbuilt, it gives me that User has no attribute country... I've revised the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Yeah the user of django as no attribute country, are you using another User model ? And don't modify your question when going further, ask another one. Now the subject and the text are not the same. 
If you want to add some fields to the User model, you need to do another model. But ask another question it's gonna be complicated to answer all your questions here